# Show events as per Custom posts date Elementor

Tags: wordpress, filter, custom-post-type, elementor, posts

Iam using PODs Plugin to create Custom post type "event_calendar". This "event_calendar" contain custom field called "event_date". Iam displaying these events on the Elementor page using Elementor post widget. This widget order posts whether ascending or descending as per "post published date" and not the event date. I want to show post as per my custom post field date order "event_date". Can any body provide code that I should insert directly to function.php. Thanks

I have used this code but its nor working

```
function my_query_by_post_meta( $query ) {

// Get current meta Query
$meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

// If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
if ( ! $meta_query ) {
    $meta_query = [];
}

// Append our meta query
$meta_query[] = [

    'key'       => 'start_date',
    'value'     => date("d/m/Y"),
    'compare'   => '<',
    'type'      => 'DATE'
    

];

$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

}

add_action( 'elementor/query/custom_order', 'my_query_by_post_meta' );

Comment: The meta key you used in the query is start_date while you want to be event_date. In your example you are looking for specific date which is todays date. For the sorting part you need to set orderby like this  $query->set( 'orderby', 'event_date' ); Maybe check this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/397690/custom-meta-query-order-for-elementor-based-on-post-meta-key

Comment: I want o show events as per their happening dates. recent first. Can you send me complete for this so that i put that in function.php

Comment: I have try this code now but its not working       

function my_query_by_post_types( $query ) {

$query->set( 'orderby', 'event_date' ); 
 
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/sorting_custom', 'my_query_by_post_types' );